# Sendkeys not working in iOS real device using Appium

Tags: ios, appium, native

I am using appium (v1.10.0) for automating iOS native app on macOS(10.13.6) using Xcode 10.1 on a real device (iPhone 6s) of platform version 12.1.3. When I start appium server and start session, the app will open in the device. Once I run the code in eclipse to send the Username to login page of the app, mobile keyboard is not getting opened and hence sendkeys() is not working.

Tried getKeyboard() before sendkeys(). Still the error exists. Below is the code which I tried.

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

    cap.setCapability("device", "iPhone");

    cap.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 6s");

    cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "12.1.3");

    cap.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");

     
    cap.setCapability("app","/Users/TP/Desktop/SampleApp.ipa" );

    cap.setCapability("udid", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    cap.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");

    cap.setCapability("xcodeOrgId", "xxxxxxxx");

    cap.setCapability("xcodeSigningId", "xxxxxxxx");
    
    driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
        
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name=\"TBI\"]")).click();
                
    driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys("abc");
```

Mobile keyboard is not getting opened and hence throwing the following error.

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>
> Original error: Error Domain=com.facebook.WebDriverAgent Code=1 "Only actions of 'pointer' type are supported. 'key' is given instead for action with id 'keyboard'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Only actions of 'pointer' type are supported. 'key' is given instead for action with id 'keyboard'}

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use `getKeyboard()` you can directly send the value to the fields

Comment: Tried without using getKeyboard(). Still there was an error.

Answer (score 0):

Send Keys sends a sequence of key strokes to an element.
Can you replace the following two lines

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name=\"TBI\"]")).click();

driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys("abc");
```

with

```
MobileElement mobileElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name=\"TBI\"]"));
mobileElement.sendKeys("abc");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Worked for me:

```
IWebElement currentElement = driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement();
currentElement.SendKeys("any text");
```